Making a loop for Fastq Quality control in Biopyton
I am trying to make this into a loop because I have many files, I am using Biopython but I am not sure if it is possible.
good_reads = (
    rec
    for rec in SeqIO.parse(rec1, "fastq")
    if max(rec.letter_annotations["phred_quality"]) >= 30
)
count = SeqIO.write(good_reads, "rec1.fastq", "fastq")

Given that I have rec1, rec2, etc... .

Were you able to figure this out Alejandra? If I understood your question correctly, what you need is to write the for lop to iterate over a list of rec1, rec2, etc.

My attempt:
Given inputs:
fastq_1.fq :
@SEQ_ID_1_1
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65

fastq_2.fq :
@SEQ_ID_1_3
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65
@SEQ_ID_2_3
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

fastq_3.fq :
@SEQ_ID_1_2
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65
@SEQ_ID_2_2
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65

and code :

from Bio import SeqIO

import Bio

print('\n-------------------------------')

print('\n Biopython Version : ', Bio.__version__)

print('\n-------------------------------')


fq_list = ['fastq_1.fq' , 'fastq_2.fq', 'fastq_3.fq'  ]

good_reads = ([(rec.format("fastq") for rec  in SeqIO.parse(seq, "fastq") if max(rec.letter_annotations["phred_quality"]) >= 30) for seq in fq_list ])


print('\n\ngood_reads : ', good_reads)

# this one empties the generators list
# for i in good_reads:
#     print(*i)      
    
with open("good_reads_2.fasta", "w+") as output_handle:
    
    for recs in good_reads:
        for rec in recs:
            output_handle.write(rec)

output good_reads_2.fasta :
@SEQ_ID_1_1
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65
@SEQ_ID_1_3
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65
@SEQ_ID_1_2
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65
@SEQ_ID_2_2
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65


I am not an expert of sequencing but perhaps this two links shed more light on base quality score :
FASTQ Phred33 average base quality score
Averaging basecall quality scores the right way
Let us know if they are meaningful or not
ADDENDUM :
using itertools.chain :
from Bio import SeqIO

import Bio

from itertools import chain

print('\n-------------------------------')

print('\n Biopython Version : ', Bio.__version__)

print('\n-------------------------------')


fq_list = ['fastq_1.fq' , 'fastq_2.fq', 'fastq_3.fq'  ]

good_reads = [*chain(*((rec.format("fastq") for rec  in SeqIO.parse(seq, "fastq") if max(rec.letter_annotations["phred_quality"]) >= 30) for seq in fq_list))]

#same result with:
# good_reads = [*chain.from_iterable((rec.format("fastq") for rec  in SeqIO.parse(seq, "fastq") if max(rec.letter_annotations["phred_quality"]) >= 30) for seq in fq_list)]

print('\n\ngood_reads : ', good_reads)

# now good_reads is a list
for i in good_reads:
    print(i)      
    
with open("good_reads_3.fasta", "w+") as output_handle:
    for rec in good_reads:
            output_handle.write(rec)

same result of one above
